# Not the real part of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am confused by the following:

I have to show that the function $u:\mathbb{C}-0 \to \mathbb{R}, u(x,y)=ln(x^2+y^2)$ is not the real part of a holomorphic function.

My attempts: Assume there is a holomorphic function $f$ with real part $u$. Then Cauchy-Schwarz-Equation yield for the imaginary part, say $v$,
$\partial_x v(x,y)=\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}$

$\partial_y v(x,y)=-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}$.

However, if I integrate the first equation over x and the second over y, I get

$v(x,y)=2\arctan(\frac{y}{x})+C(x)$ and
$v(x,y)=2\arctan(\frac{x}{y})+C'(y)$.

I think this is a contradiction because the both equations cannot be solved over the complex numbers.

However, $u$ IS part of a holomorphic function $f(x,y)=\ln(x^2+y^2)+2\arctan(y/x)$. Where is my mistake?

I know the solution where one shows that arctan(y/x) is not continuous over the complex numbers. But what is wrong in my attempt of solution.

Comment: Intuitively, the holomorphic function "would be" a branch of the complex logarithm (up to a factor), but the argument of a complex number cannot be made into a holomorphic function on all of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Any attempt to do so requires a branch cut (the usual one being on the nonpositive real axis).

Answer (score 4):

As Ian said, intuitively, if $\log|z|^2$ were the real part of $f$ then $f$ would be a constant plus $2\log(z)$, and there's no globally defined $\log(z)$ (for example because $\arctan(y/x)$ is not continuous, whatever).

Here's a way to nail it down with no fuzziness: Suppose that $\log|z|^2$ is the real part of $f$. Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show that $$f'(z)=\frac2z.$$ This is impossible: If $C$ is any closed curve the fundamental theorem of calculus shows that $$\int_Cf'(z)\,dz=0,$$while if $C$ is the unit circle then $$\int_C\frac{dz}{z}=2\pi i.$$

Comment: Thanks for this intuition. Can you say on which branches the function $f(x,y)=ln(x^2+y^2)+2arctan(y/x)$ is a holomorphic function?

Comment: @user3849393 Well, I really don't think that's the best way to look at it - it certainly doesn't seem to me to be the simplest way to give a rigorous proof, you need to get into analytic continuation and so on. If you insist, note that that function is just a branch of $\log(z)$ and see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm .

Comment: If I may ask an unrelated:. I know , by Schwarz Reflection, a Holomorphic function may map Reals to Reals. Could that same function map Complexes to Complexes?

Comment: @MSIS Huh? Every holomorphic function maps a subset of the complex numbers to the complex numbers

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : Sorry, I was imprecise. Let $f$ from Complexes to Complexes be holomorphic.  Can f map the Real axis $ \{ x+i0 \} $ to the Real axis and the Imaginary axis  $\{ 0+ia \} $ to the Imaginary axis ; say $ f(0)=0$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich : I meant a function other than $f(z)=cz ; c$ a Real constant.

Comment: $z+z^5$. I bet an entire function maps the reals to the reals and the imaginaries to the imaginaries if and only if it's $\sum a_j z^{4j+1}$, $a_j$ real

Comment: Whoops. Change that to $z+z^3$, and the general conjecture to $f$ odd with all real coefficients.